# python shell from nodeJS script returns same values to nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have wrote the following program based on the issue i am facing in my other application,in below program i am calling the python script from nodejs to get some job done ,the python scripts returns some results which is further used in nodejs.

`nodeJS :`

```
var pythonShell = require('python-shell');

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
  for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
    if(i==j){
        var options = {
          mode: 'text',
          scriptPath: 'python file path',
          pythonPath: 'python.exe path',
          env : process.env,
          args: [i]
        };
        console.log("====calling Python script for ====",i," ",j);   
          pythonShell.run('check.py', options, function(err, results){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            } 
            else {
              console.log("====Python result for ====",i," ",j);                    
              console.log(results[0]);
            }    
          });
    }
  }
}
```

`check.py`

```
import sys

k = sys.argv[1]
print(k)
limit=10000000
if(k==2):
    limit=3
if(k==1):
    limit=2
s=0
for i in range(limit):
    for j in range(10):
        s+=1

print(s," i = ",k)
```

`Output of nodeJs script`

```
====calling Python script for ==== 0   0
====calling Python script for ==== 1   1
====calling Python script for ==== 2   2
====Python result for ==== 2   2
100000000  i =  2
====Python result for ==== 0   0
100000000  i =  0
====Python result for ==== 1   1
100000000  i =  1
```

Here from the above code you can see that, i am getting the same output even the `forloop` is running for less time for i=1 and i=2,Don't know what is going on.
Thanks in advance.

`edit` : Displaying results with parameters passed in python script

```
====Python result for ==== 1   1
[ '1\r', '100000000  i =  1\r' ]
====Python result for ==== 0   0
[ '0\r', '100000000  i =  0\r' ]
====Python result for ==== 2   2
[ '2\r', '100000000  i =  2\r' ]
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in python script. The place you are calling the python script may be the problem.

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa yeah python script has no issues, only problem i can see that is the IO issue..

Comment: I think the value passed to the python script is always not equals to 1 or 2. Because script has been executed in any case. parameter passing is the problem'

Comment: made an edit pls check `parameters` going in is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem here is python script gets passing argument as a `string`. So always conditions inside the python script become `false`. What you can do is cast string into an integer.
Try this in your python code:

```
import sys

k = int(sys.argv[1])
limit=10000000
if(k==2):
    limit=3
if(k==1):
    limit=2
s=0
for i in range(limit):
    for j in range(10):
        s+=1

print(s," i = ",k)
```

In here you can do

`k = int(sys.argv[1])` - cast into an integer

or

```
if(k=='2'):
   limit=3
if(k=='1'):
   limit=2
```